# What is Neutronium and Hydrogen in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

What is neutronium and Hydrogen in ionic. I have seen this term in some blogs and i was wondering what is Neutronium and Hydrogen in ionic.

Comment: You can look it up on ionic website...

Comment: Have a look at this http://masteringionic.com/blog/2019-01-27-ionic-4-neutronium-released/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in ionic Neutronium is Ionic 4 version which is a major release in ionic and Minor versions are called according to the order of periodic table by atomic number. Ionic 4.1 Hydrogen, Ionic 4.2 Helium, 4.3 Lithium, etc.